# Convert Decimal Number to time

Tags: db2

How to convert decimal number to time. suppose if I have a decimal number 2.56 by converting it into the time it would be 02:33:36.

-->CREATE TABLE t1(COL1 INTEGER NOT NULL,COL2 DECIMAL(10,2));

-->insert into t1(col1,clo2 )
    values(1024 ,  2.56 ),
          (1024 ,  4.23 ),
          (1024 ,  1.67 ),
          (1024 ,  0.56 )

Answer (score 0):

```
$ db2 "select i, j
  ,  time('00.00.00') 
     + int(j) hours 
     + int(mod(j,1)*60) minutes 
     + int(mod(mod(j,1)*60*60,60)) seconds as time
  from table( values(1024 , 2.56 ), (1024 , 4.23 )
                  , (1024 , 1.67 ), (1024 , 0.56 )
            ) a(i,j)"

I           J     TIME    
----------- ----- --------
       1024  2.56 02:33:36
       1024  4.23 04:13:48
       1024  1.67 01:40:12
       1024  0.56 00:33:36

  4 record(s) selected.
```

BTW you should store time values a `TIME` datatype not `DECIMAL`

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for replay. In my case, the query is not working as it is showing only 00:00:00. And I checked with " int(mod(mod(REGULARHRS,1)*60*60,60)) " it is also showing as 0.

Comment: You did not mention `REGULARHRS` in your original post. What data type is it. What Db2 version are you using.  I'm sure you can debug this yourself! Maybe try casting the column to DECFLOAT or a larger DECIMAL first.  Or if really stuck, try asking in a new post, but make more effort to document your exact issue, and the code that you have tried so far, but which is not working